# PNCircle chart will not update when increment by button press

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I am new in iOS and I want to implement a framework call PNChart to my project. I would like to increment the circle chart by one but the UI will not update. Please help.

[image: Circle chart screenshot]

```
import UIKit
import PNChart

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    //global var
    let number = NSNumber(value: 70)

    //obj outlet
    @IBOutlet weak var circleChart: PNCircleChart!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        let myCgrect = CGRect(
            x: self.view.bounds.width/2 - 40,
            y: self.view.bounds.height/2 - 40,
            width: 100, height: 100)

        let circleChart = PNCircleChart(
            frame: myCgrect, total: Int(100) as NSNumber!,
            current: number, clockwise: false,
            shadow: false, shadowColor: UIColor.red)

        circleChart?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        circleChart?.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
        circleChart?.stroke()

        self.view.addSubview(circleChart!)
    }

    @IBAction func increaseCircle(_ sender: Any) {
        _ = NSNumber(value: number.intValue + 1)
        print("btnpressed")
    }
}// end uiviewcontroller
```

Answer (score 0):

In your function increaseCircle you aren't doing anything with the information. You need to feed in this incremented number into your circleChart and redraw it. Since you're customizing Gindi's library you probably have your own functions for doing this.

Comment: Thanks you so much... that make sense now